# Dreamviewer & Zend Framework project: Wrong path mapping

Tags: php, zend-framework, ide, dreamweaver

I tried all the day to set up a Zend Framework project in Dreamweaver CS5.5. Now, after a few hours spending on google and the CS5.5 doc, i am still not able to debug a Zend Framework project in Dreamweaver:

Let's say, i have a module called "admin" in `/application/modules/admin`. If i try the Live View feature, Live Code, or the dynamic files discover, it fails at all.

If I try to debug the IndexController of the AdminModule, Dreamweaver always tries to render the page `http://foo.bar/application/modules/admin/controllers/IndexController.php`, insteadof `http://foo.bar/admin[/index/index]`

Is there any way to get those features working with Dreamweaver CS5.5?

Also, the include path does not work. The `/public/index.php` includes something like `require_once 'Zend/Application.php';`. Where does Dreamweaver search? He tells me that he can not find the file `http://foo.bar/Zend/Application.php`. Omg, srsly?

I hope there are some Dreamweaver PHP developers out there which can help me.

Btw, I am using Zend Studio at the moment and wanted to get a "quick" look into the new CS5.5 features :/

**Update 16.05.2012**

Little update from me. I'm currently Using [PHPStorm from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). It is the best IDE I ever had. (Ecpilse/Aptana/Zend Studio/PHPDesigner). Autocomplete for nearly everything, huge plugin repository and much nice features like LESS Support, NodeJS Support, PHPUnit integration or an integrated Git Client. Give it a try. It's free for open source projects.

Comment: Well, I think that was my ubconscious mind, while translating my problem to english ;)

Comment: Zend Studio much better than Dreamweaver for Zend Framework development. Don't waste your time on Dreamweaver.

Comment: Quite frankly I would not use Dreamweaver for ANY php project. Dreamweaver is great for creating your designs but not php coding.

Comment: +1 Adrian World, I actually go one step further and make it a point to **never** use Dreamweaver on **any** project, HTML, PHP, whatever.
Using Dreamweaver you are doomed to extremely ugly, and hard to read code. The only thing I ever use it for is the mass FTP (backing up entire websites), other than that, I never open it.

Comment: Have you tried Netbeans ? The PHP version of Netbeans have AMAZING Zend Framework support. Best of all, it is FREE :)

Comment: Belongs on superuser, no professional programmer or designer would know anything about Dreamweaver and if they do they should try to forget about it as quick as they can.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver can technically work with anything, but it's really designed to work with procedural php.

I would recommend the eclipse software with the pdt plugin or net beans.  WAY better for supporting a zend framework project imo.

I'm not bagging on dreamweaver, it's a nice tool (especially for html/css), but for OO PHP programming, it's really not designed for it.